# Show $\max\{f-g,0\} + g=\max\{f,g\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, intuition, solution-verification

As stated in the title:

> Show that for a given variable $x$ it holds $max\{(f-g)(x),0\}+g(x)=max\{f(x),g(x)\}$, where $f,g$ are functions.

I just came across the above stated expression and I am wondering if it is sufficient to check the two cases $f(x)\geq g(x)$ and $f(x)<g(x)$. Or do I have to use/verify further assumptions?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are functions, it is not true in general that either $f \geq g$ or $f < g$ (meaning that the inequality holds for any input $x$), so you should rather fix some input $x$ and check the cases $f(x) \geq g(x)$ and $f(x) < g(x)$

Comment: I disagree @frafour. Yes it is enough to check for those cases only, that is because max{f,g} is to mean max{f(x),g(x)} for some x. otherwise it has no other meaning.  assume $$ f(x) = 2*x $$ and  $$ g(x) = x*x $$ , what would be max{f,g} unless we are dealing with a particular value? hence max{f,g} gives a value and not a function.

Comment: @Babydesta: If $f$ and $g$ are functions then $\max ( f, g)$ is a function. Writing it out explicitly might use different expressions for different values of $x$, but that is a common and accepted way of defining a function. (For at least 100 years. Further back you could have an argument over whether a piece-wise defined function was really a function, but not these days.)

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC, I understand what you mean, but you have to meet me halfway. A function in arithmetic has no meaning unless it has inputs and outputs. That is you define functions as relations from one set of values to another. now maximum has no meaning for functions, nor does addition of functions. when one says $f+g$ we know it means the function $h(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ and f(x) & g(x) are values. Basically every function operation is defined based on the input and output values. So we only define maximum of a function based on its output.

Comment: The process you're describing extends "maximum" and "addition" from being defined for numbers to being defined for functions. And, as you note, we (usually) do so "based on its output", which is usually described as "point-wise", i.e. we __define__ $f+g$ by $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+ g(x)$. Once we've done this, addition is defined for functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is $\max \{f,g\}$ defined?

Remember that for any two numbers $x,y$: $$\max \{x,y\} ={x+y+|x-y|\over 2}$$

and this is easy to prove.